# Applying conditionalPanel logic where one switchInput is set to TRUE, and a slider has different inputs

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs, shiny-reactivity

I'm implementing a R Shiny app, and my Javascript skills are not strong.

I'm struggling to come up with the conditional logic in the `conditionalPanel()`. How do I have `id3` only shown if `id1` is set to TRUE, AND the slider range `id2` has different selections?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  materialSwitch(inputId = "id1", label = "Do I want this on?", value = FALSE, status = "primary"),
  sliderTextInput(inputId = "id2", label = "Show below if the range is greater than 0", choices = 2000:2018, selected = rep(2018, 2)),
  br(), br(),
  conditionalPanel("input.id1 && input.id2[1] != input.id2[2]",
               materialSwitch(inputId = "id3", label = "To show based on conditions above.", value = FALSE, status = "primary")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've also toyed with the `shinyjs` package, but I haven't had any success either (attempt below):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  materialSwitch(inputId = "id1", label = "Do I want this on?", value = FALSE, status = "primary"),
  sliderTextInput(inputId = "id2", label = "Show below if the range is greater than 0", choices = 2000:2018, selected = rep(2018, 2)),
  br(), br(),
  hidden(
    p(id = "element", materialSwitch(inputId = "id3", label = "To show based on conditions above.", value = FALSE, status = "primary"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if (input$id1 == TRUE && (input$id2[1] != input$id2[2])) {
      show("element")
    }
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: is it 'input.id1 & input.id2[1] != input.ids[2]' intentional or do you want to use && here?

Comment: Not intentional, just trying to find the solution.

Comment: to check the AND condition, you should use &&

Comment: Sure. Either way doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: input.id1 && input.id2.value != input.id1.value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that Javascript uses a zero-base index, unlike R.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  materialSwitch(inputId = "id1", label = "Do I want this on?", value = FALSE, status = "primary"),
  sliderTextInput(inputId = "id2", label = "Show below if the range is greater than 0", choices = 2000:2018, selected = rep(2018, 2)),
  br(), br(),
  conditionalPanel("input.id1 && input.id2[0] != input.id2[1]",
           materialSwitch(inputId = "id3", label = "To show based on conditions above.", value = FALSE, status = "primary")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```